# Extended Array works in Angular component view, but not Angular component class

Tags: angular, typescript

I am extending the Javascript base array object for an Angular app using Typescript via the following code:

File: utilities.ts

```
// --- Extends Array object to include a getIndexBy method. ---
interface Array<T> {
    getIndexBy(name: string, value: T): number;
}

// --- Returns the index of an object based on the name and value passed into the method.
Array.prototype.getIndexBy = function(name, value) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i][name] === value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
};
```

File: app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'utilities';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
    items: Array<{ name: string, age: number }> = [{
        name: 'steve',
        age: 20
    }, {
        name: 'bob',
        age: 12
    }, {
        name: 'john',
        age: 40
    }];

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.items.getIndexBy('age', 20));
        // ERROR - Argument of type '20' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; age: number; }'
    }
}
```

File: app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<hr>
{{items.getIndexBy('age', 12)}} <!-- Works as expected -->
{{items.getIndexBy('name', 'john')}} <!-- Works as expected -->
```

How come I can use the extended array method in the view, but not in the component class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a typescript error because the types don't match. You defined getIndexBy like this:

```
getIndexBy(name: string, value: T): number
```

Where T is the type of the array. Your array is Array<{ name: string, age: number}>, so passing 20 does not match {name: string, age: number}. Exactly how to fix this depends on what your intentions are. Did you mean to make getIndexBy be a generic?

You see this error only in the .ts file and not the .html file, because the typescript checking is not done on the .html file.

Comment: I see. Yes, my intention was to make the getIndexBy method accept a second generic parameter

Answer (score 0):

Updating the utilities file with the following corrected the issue.

```
interface Array<T> {
    getIndexBy<U>(name: string, value: U): number;
}
```